# Plotting the branches of a complex function

Tags: matlab, plot, visualization, complex-numbers, surface

I'm trying to plot a kind of Riemann's surface of a function (I'm not sure if it's the right name for the thing), as shown below:

[image: Desired result]

Here's what I tried:

```
r = (0:1:15)';                           % create a matrix of complex inputs
theta = pi*(-1:0.05:1);
z = r*exp(1i*theta);
w = z.^(1/2)  ;                          % calculate the complex outputs

figure('Name','Graphique complexe','units','normalized','outerposition',[ 0.08 0.1 0.8 0.55]);
subplot(121)

surf(real(z),imag(z),real(w),imag(w))    % visualize the complex function using surf
xlabel('Real(z)')
ylabel('Imag(z)')
zlabel('Real(u)')
cb = colorbar;
colormap jet;                            % gradient from blue to red
cb.Label.String = 'Imag(v)';

subplot(122)
surf(real(z),imag(z),imag(w),real(w))    % visualize the complex function using surf
xlabel('Real(z)')
ylabel('Imag(z)')
zlabel('Imag(v)')
cb = colorbar;
colormap jet;                            % gradient from blue to red
cb.Label.String = 'Real(u)';
```

Which gives me the following:

[image: Current result]

My questions are:

1. I thought I would plot what is on the first image, but I got something else. What did I plot if it isn't a Riemann's surface?
2. How can I change my code to get the top plot?
3. Would it be possible have a scale in radians on the first graph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first plot shows multiple branches of a multiple-valued "function". It's not really a function in the usual sense, since for a given `z` you have more than one function value. You can only reproduce this by going around more than once around the origin, i.e. more than `2*pi` in your angular variable. What you plot is the principal branch of that function, i.e. the sheet that corresponds to complex phases ranging from `-pi` to `pi`.

Furthermore, there's a more fundamental issue. Once you switch to complex numbers represented as doubles, you lose any information about additional phase around the origin (complex numbers represented as a real + imaginary part will only result in the principal value of their complex phase, which falls between `-pi` and `pi`). So you need to compute the square root "manually", from the trigonometric form of the complex number:

```
r = (0:1:15)';                           % create a matrix of complex inputs
theta = pi*(-2:0.05:2);
z = r*exp(1i*theta);
%w = z.^(1/2)  ;                          % calculate the complex outputs
w = sqrt(r)*exp(1i*theta/2);

figure('Name','Graphique complexe','units','normalized','outerposition',[ 0.08 0.1 0.8 0.55]);
subplot(121)

surf(real(z),imag(z),real(w),imag(w))    % visualize the complex function using surf
xlabel('Real(z)')
ylabel('Imag(z)')
zlabel('Real(u)')
cb = colorbar;
colormap jet;                            % gradient from blue to red
cb.Label.String = 'Imag(v)';

subplot(122)
surf(real(z),imag(z),imag(w),real(w))    % visualize the complex function using surf
xlabel('Real(z)')
ylabel('Imag(z)')
zlabel('Imag(v)')
cb = colorbar;
colormap jet;                            % gradient from blue to red
cb.Label.String = 'Real(u)';
```

[image: result from polar solution]

As you can see, the function acts as it should. Note that it doesn't make sense to have "the scale in radians" in the figure. Everything you plot has "linear" dimensions: real parts and imaginary parts. Radians would only make sense for *angles*, i.e. `theta`-like quantities.

Also, you may note that the above figure has round edges, since we're plotting using polar coordinates. It's possible to create a rectangular plot but it takes a lot more work. Here's a partial solution. The idea is to sew together the same mesh twice in order to plot the two branches of the function:

```
r0 = 15;
re = linspace(-r0, r0, 31).';                           % create a matrix of complex inputs
im = linspace(-r0, r0, 31);
z = re + 1j*im;
theta = angle(z);  % atan2(imag(z), real(z));
r = abs(z);

% concatenate the same mesh twice (plotting trick) back to back, insert nan in between
w1 = sqrt(r).*exp(1i*theta/2); % first branch
w2 = sqrt(r).*exp(1i*(theta+2*pi)/2); % second branch

z = [z, nan(size(w1,1),1), z(:,end:-1:1)];
w = [w1, nan(size(w1,1),1), w2(:,end:-1:1)];

figure('Name','Graphique complexe','units','normalized','outerposition',[ 0.08 0.1 0.8 0.55]);
subplot(121)
surf(real(z),imag(z),real(w),imag(w))    % visualize the complex function using surf
xlabel('Real(z)')
ylabel('Imag(z)')
zlabel('Real(u)')
cb = colorbar;
colormap jet;                            % gradient from blue to red
cb.Label.String = 'Imag(v)';

subplot(122)
surf(real(z),imag(z),imag(w),real(w))    % visualize the complex function using surf
xlabel('Real(z)')
ylabel('Imag(z)')
zlabel('Imag(v)')
cb = colorbar;
colormap jet;                            % gradient from blue to red
cb.Label.String = 'Real(u)';
```

Here's the result:

[image: result from Cartesian solution]

As you can see the complex part looks weird. This is because the phase of complex numbers jumps along the negative real half axis. This *could* be remedied but takes a lot more work, this is left as an exercise to the reader. The reason I injected a column of `nan`s into the data is to prevent a similar jump artifact to be present in the first plot. The other option is to plot the two branches of the function separately, with `hold on` in between, but then extra work would have to be done to normalize the colormap on the figures.

Finally, do consider not using `jet` but the default `parula` colormap instead. Jet is very bad for people with impaired colour vision, and `parula` is close to perceptually uniform. For a short introduction to the problem I suggest watching [this great talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAoljeRJ3lU) from the scipy guys.

Comment: nice talk. Thank you for the help !

Comment: The author has also posted a Python version of this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63144641/208273).