# How can I create a 4D complex surface plot?

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, 3d

I have the following Matlab code that I would like to be converted to a Python 3 one.

```matlab
r = (0:1:15)';                           % create a matrix of complex inputs
theta = pi*(-2:0.05:2);
z = r*exp(1i*theta);
%w = z.^(1/2)  ;                          % calculate the complex outputs
w = sqrt(r)*exp(1i*theta/2);

figure('Name','Graphique complexe','units','normalized','outerposition',[ 0.08 0.1 0.8 0.55]);
subplot(121)

surf(real(z),imag(z),real(w),imag(w))    % visualize the complex function using surf
xlabel('Real(z)')
ylabel('Imag(z)')
zlabel('Real(u)')
cb = colorbar;
colormap jet;                            % gradient from blue to red
cb.Label.String = 'Imag(v)';

subplot(122)
surf(real(z),imag(z),imag(w),real(w))    % visualize the complex function using surf
xlabel('Real(z)')
ylabel('Imag(z)')
zlabel('Imag(v)')
cb = colorbar;
colormap jet;                            % gradient from blue to red
cb.Label.String = 'Real(u)';
```

The results and original discussions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53234466/plotting-the-branches-of-a-complex-function). There's also a discussion available on this [SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22175533/what-is-the-equivalent-of-matlabs-surfx-y-z-c-in-matplotlib/23799389#23799389). However, I failed to run and reproduce those codes. What can I try next?

Comment: You are in a terrible amount of luck, because I always close such code requests, but in this specific case I couldn't pass on the fun of porting _my own MATLAB code_ to python. So, I hope you'll use the result for good. Do learn the basics of python and matplotlib, please.

Comment: @hbaromega: Some useful feedback: the phrase _Any help?_ at the end of questions may appear to native English speakers as rather entitled. It may also appear to transfer the responsibility of solving _your_ problem to readers. In general, you may have a better reception if you phrase your questions in a way that shows you are still happy and willing to do the bulk of the work.

Comment: @halfer Sorry I was a bit way for the past few days. Thanks for correcting me and I'll remember this advice in the future.

Comment: No worries, thanks for considering it `:-)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is perfectly straightforward if you spend the time learning how matplotlib (and 3d axes in particular) work:

```py
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import matplotlib.cm as cm 
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D 
 
# compute data to plot 
r, theta = np.mgrid[1:16, -2*np.pi:2*np.pi:50j] 
z = r * np.exp(1j*theta)  
w = np.sqrt(r) * np.exp(1j*theta/2)  
 
# plot data  
fig = plt.figure()  
for plot_index in [1, 2]: 
    if plot_index == 1: 
        z_data, c_data = w.real, w.imag 
        z_comp, c_comp = 'Re', 'Im' 
    else: 
        z_data, c_data = w.imag, w.real 
        z_comp, c_comp = 'Im', 'Re' 
    c_data = (c_data - c_data.min()) / c_data.ptp() 
    colors = cm.viridis(c_data) 
 
    ax = fig.add_subplot(f'12{plot_index}', projection='3d') 
    surf = ax.plot_surface(z.real, z.imag, z_data, facecolors=colors,
                           clim=[z_data.min(), z_data.max()])
    ax.set_xlabel('$Re z$')  
    ax.set_ylabel('$Im z$')   
    ax.set_zlabel(f'${z_comp} w$')  
    cb = plt.colorbar(surf, ax=ax)  
    cb.set_label(f'${c_comp} w$')  
 
plt.show()
```

The result:
[image: Nice plot showing the real and imaginary part of a complex function in 3d]

Some things that should be noted:

- Viridis colormap is good, jet is bad.
- In general there could be rendering issues with complex (interlocking) 3d geometries, because matplotlib has a 2d renderer. Fortunately, in this case the dataset is tightly coupled enough that this doesn't seem to happen, even if you rotate around the figure interactively. (But if you were to plot two intersecting surfaces together, [things would probably be different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47835726/plotting-a-2d-plane-through-a-3d-surface).)
- One might want to enable latex rendering of labels to make the result extra crispy.
- The shading looks a lot better if you use the default option of colouring according to the z component of the data.

---

If we also want to port the second part of [my MATLAB answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53250836/5067311) you will have to [use a trick to stitch together the two branches of the function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47916583/5067311) (which, as I said, is necessary to render interlocking surfaces properly). For the specific example in the above code this will not give you perfect results, since both branches themselves contain discontinuities in the imaginary part, so regardless of our efforts in rendering the two surfaces nicely, the result will look a bit bad:

```py
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.cm as cm 
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D 
 
# compute data to plot 
r0 = 15 
re, im = np.mgrid[-r0:r0:31j, -r0:r0:31j] 
z = re + 1j*im 
r, theta = abs(z), np.angle(z) 
w1 = np.sqrt(r) * np.exp(1j*theta/2)  # first branch 
w2 = np.sqrt(r) * np.exp(1j*(theta + 2*np.pi)/2)  # second branch 
 
# plot data 
fig = plt.figure() 
for plot_index in [1, 2]: 
    # construct transparent bridge 
    re_bridge = np.vstack([re[-1, :], re[0, :]]) 
    im_bridge = np.vstack([im[-1, :], im[0, :]]) 
    c_bridge = np.full(re_bridge.shape + (4,), [1, 1, 1, 0])  # 0% opacity
 
    re_surf = np.vstack([re, re_bridge, re]) 
    im_surf = np.vstack([im, im_bridge, im]) 
    w12 = np.array([w1, w2]) 
    if plot_index == 1: 
        z_comp, c_comp = 'Re', 'Im' 
        z12, c12 = w12.real, w12.imag 
    else: 
        z_comp, c_comp = 'Im', 'Re' 
        z12, c12 = w12.imag, w12.real 
         
    color_arrays = cm.viridis((c12 - c12.min()) / c12.ptp()) 
    z1,z2 = z12 
    c1,c2 = color_arrays 
     
    z_bridge = np.vstack([z1[-1, :], z2[0, :]]) 
    z_surf = np.vstack([z1, z_bridge, z2]) 
    c_surf = np.vstack([c1, c_bridge, c2]) 
     
    ax = fig.add_subplot(f'12{plot_index}', projection='3d') 
    surf = ax.plot_surface(re_surf, im_surf, z_surf, facecolors=c_surf, 
                           clim=[c12.min(), c12.max()], 
                           rstride=1, cstride=1) 
    ax.set_xlabel('$Re z$') 
    ax.set_ylabel('$Im z$') 
    ax.set_zlabel(f'${z_comp} w$') 
    cb = plt.colorbar(surf, ax=ax) 
    cb.set_label(f'${c_comp} w$') 
  
plt.show()
```

[image: 3d plot over a square domain, with an ugly jump in the imaginary part]

The ugly jump in the right figure might be fixed with a lot of work, but it won't be easy: it's an actual discontinuity in both surface datasets occuring at negative real arguments. Since your actual problem is probably [more like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63078039/riemann-surface-plot-using-python), you will probably not need to face this issue, and you can use the above stitching (bridging) trick to combine your surfaces.

Comment: Indeed, it's a stroke of luck and pleasure to get an answer from the person whose code has been quoted in the question. Now I may follow the same steps and translate the second Matlab code as well.  However, what would be the Python version for the part `z = [z, nan(size(w1,1),1), z(:,end:-1:1)]; w = [w1, nan(size(w1,1),1), w2(:,end:-1:1)];` where you're supposedly introduced NaNs to avoid the jump on the negative real half axis. Secondly, I tried to change the colormap to some other color (say `seismic`). The colorbar still remained `viridis`. Where else do I need to make a change?

Comment: @hbaromega I'm not sure how that jump trick will play in matplotlib, I'll try to check it out later. As for the colormap: you have to pass `cmap='seismic'` to the call to `plot_surface` to affect the colorbar (which is not something I've noticed; I almost always use viridis which is the default).

Comment: Thanks, `cmap='seismic'` in the arguments works like a charm. Please let me know if you succeed in coding the jump trick in Python. There's a similar post by me where I failed to generate Riemann plots for a complex matrix's eigenvalues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63078039/riemann-surface-plot-using-python?noredirect=1#comment111569992_63078039

If there's an option for a private chat, it could be helpful as well.

Comment: @hbaromega see my update, that's as much as we can easily do with that approach. The jump in the figure is unrelated to matplotlib's rendering issues, it's a fundamental problem with this dataset and this approach.